# Mockk - mocking javax.mail.Message - getting java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: kotlin, jakarta-mail, mockk

I want to mock instance of javax.mail.Message, but unable to. Getting java.lang.VerifyError with no message.

Running:

- Kotlin - 1.3.10
- Mockk - 1.9

Simple code:

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.Test
import javax.mail.Message

class MessageTest {

  private val message = mockk<Message>()

  @Test
  fun testMockMessage() {
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InlineInstrumentation.execute(InlineInstrumentation.kt:39)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.inline(ProxyMaker.kt:88)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactory.newProxy(JvmMockFactory.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.newProxy$default(AbstractMockFactory.kt:29)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.mockk(AbstractMockFactory.kt:58)
    at service.mailer.MailerTest.<init>(MailerTest.kt:32)
```

Tried to mock the same thing in Java tests with org.easymock.Mock and had no problem there. Any ideas?